# Testing-library/react-native issue with expo-vector-icons

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

expo-vector-icons package is causing unit tests to break with SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

We have a file to mock the packages if necessary?
Reading other post, seeing stuff about transformIgnorePatterns, but nothing is working.

```
  console.warn
    The "EXNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules; verify that expo-modules-core's native code is linked properly

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-modules-core/src/NativeModulesProxy.native.ts:74:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-modules-core/src/index.ts:4:1)

  console.warn
    No native ExponentConstants module found, are you sure the expo-constants's module is linked properly?

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-constants/src/Constants.ts:32:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-asset/src/PlatformUtils.ts:2:1)

 FAIL  __tests__/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/dillon/repos/MyApp/MyApp-MobileApp/node_modules/expo-vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){
                                                                                             

    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-vector-icons/src/AntDesign.ts:2:1)

Summary of all failing tests
 FAIL  __tests__/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/dillon/repos/MyApp/MyApp-MobileApp/node_modules/expo-vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){
                                                                                             

    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-vector-icons/src/AntDesign.ts:2:1)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried `jest.mock('react-native-vector-icons')`?

Comment: Yes also jest.mock('expo-vector-icons') and others